# Keras loss of inference and forward propagation don't match

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIijW.png)

I am using Keras pre-trained model ResNet50 to train my own dateset, which contains only one image for testing purpose. First, I evaluate the model with my image and get a loss of 0.5 and an accuracy of 1. Then, I fit the model and get a loss of 6 and an accuracy of 0. I don't understand why the loss of inference and forward propagation don't match. It seems like the behaviors of inference and forward propagation in Keras are different. I have attached my code snippet and the screenshot of it.

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

y = np.zeros((1, 1000))
y[0, 386] = 1

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.evaluate(x, y)
```

> 1/1 [==============================] - 1s 547ms/step
>   [0.5232877135276794, 1.0]

```
model.fit(x, y, validation_data=(x, y))
```

> Train on 1 samples, validate on 1 samples Epoch 1/1 1/1
>   [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 6.1883 -
>   categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 9.8371e-04 -
>   val_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000

```
model.evaluate(x, y)
```

> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 74ms/step
>   [0.0009837078396230936, 1.0]

Comment: when you fit model, you update the weight once. So you evaluate same img on different models, which is supposed to have different results.

Comment: @zihaozhihao, you are right. The loss for evals before fit and after fit are different. But, before the back propagation to update the weights, the loss for eval and fit have been already different.

Comment: Maybe something to do with BN? Could you try a model without BN, like `VGG`?

Comment: BN is possible the reason. I have tried VGG16, it's the same.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen, it's a very good idea. I have tried VGG16 and the losses for eval and fit are matched to each other.  It should be the problem of BN layer.

Comment: @LeiGao Even though I freeze the BN layer, the losses are still not matched...

Comment: Actually, I even freeze all layers, the losses are not matched either.

Comment: Freezing BN layer is not something that will fix the problem. BN layer will get the "batch mean/variance" during training and the "accumulated mean/variance" during evaluation. These two groups of values will never be the same unless you are very lucky or (only for the case of single batch) you train for long enough so the moving_mean and moving_variance update considering they have momentum.

Comment: Also, by design, the formulas of Batch Normalization are different in training and evaluation. One of them compensates for the fact that you're using single batch and uses a statistically-thought way of increasing the variance.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you for you clear explanation. I have figured out this problem :)

Comment: @DanielMöller So during the evaluation, BN layer will use the EMA of training phase to do the inference, right? But when we use `fit`, the BN layer will calculate the new EMA of training dataset. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Another question is what's the differences between `K.set_learning_pahse(0)` and freeze all layers?

Comment: I don't know which type of moving average they use (if it's an EMA or not). They use "the batch" mean and variance during training and "the moving average" during inference/evaluation. --- I don't understand the details of learning phase and the values that the `training` parameter may assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstanding the question at first. The problem is very tricky. And the problem is likely caused by BatchNorm layer as @Natthaphon mentioned in the comments, because I have tried on VGG16, the losses are matched.

Then I tested in ResNet50, and eval loss and fit loss are still not matched even though I "freeze" all layers. Actually, I manually check the BN weights, they're indeed not changed.

```py
from keras.applications import ResNet50, VGG16
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras_preprocessing import image
import keras
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

img_path = '/home/zhihao/Downloads/elephant.jpeg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

y = np.zeros((1, 1000))
y[0, 386] = 1

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.evaluate(x, y)
# 1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step
# [0.2981376349925995, 1.0]

model.fit(x, y, validation_data=(x, y))
# Train on 1 samples, validate on 1 samples
# Epoch 1/1
# 1/1 [==============================] - 1s 549ms/step - loss: 5.3056 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2981 - val_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
```

We can notice that eval loss is 0.2981 and fit loss is 5.3056. I guess Batch Norm layers have different behaviors between **eval** mode and **train** mode. Correct me if I'm wrong.

One way to really freeze the model I found is using `K.set_learning_phase(0)` as following,

```py
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

K.set_learning_phase(0)  # all new operations will be in test mode from now on

model.fit(x, y, validation_data=(x, y))

# Train on 1 samples, validate on 1 samples
# Epoch 1/1
# 1/1 [==============================] - 4s 4s/step - loss: 0.2981 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Now the two losses are matched.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could force the learning phase to be training mode and print out the weight and output of BN layer to see what's happening inside.

Comment: This issue happens due to the property of BN operation. Briefly, during inference, BN will use mean and variance calculated from the whole training set, which is the imageNet, to perform forward propagation, but during training process, it will use a new set of mean and variance calculated from the current training set, which is a image. So that causes the outputs of BN layer are different for eval and fit. Sorry for not explaining very well. There are tons of blogs talking about the behavior of BN layer.

Comment: So, `K.set_learning_phase(0)` will set BN layer to eval mode, right?

Comment: That is right.  Daniel Möller has explained the problem in the comment above